# Loop through EDI to XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, foreach

I am new to XSLT and XML, so forgive my terminology if it is incorrect. I have an XML file, which is converted from an EDI file, specifically an 835 that I am currently trying to map to a SQL table. I am using XSLT after the EDI file is converted to XML in order to load it in. Here is a snippet of the XML, so you can see what it would look like, (note, this loads in one line currently, as I know I must loop in order to insert all lines. I just don't understand the proper structure for nodes, and subnodes(?), when I have nodes such as LOOP_2000, with sub nodes such as LOOP_2100, and a sub node which is named LOOP_2110)

```
<!--LOOP 2000 Columns-->
                        <!--LX Columns-->
                        <_2000_LX01_AssignedNumber>
                            <xsl:value-of 
select="transaction/LOOP_2000/LX/LX01" />
                        </_2000_LX01_AssignedNumber>

<!--LOOP 2000 Columns-->
<!--CAS Columns-->
                        <_2100_CAS01_ClaimAdjustmentGroupCode>
                            <xsl:value-of 
select="transaction/LOOP_2000/LOOP_2100/CAS/CAS01" />
                        </_2100_CAS01_ClaimAdjustmentGroupCode>
                        <_2100_CAS02_AdjustmentReasonCode>
                            <xsl:value-of 
select="transaction/LOOP_2000/LOOP_2100/CAS/CAS02" />
                        </_2100_CAS02_AdjustmentReasonCode>
                        <_2100_CAS03_AdjustmentAmount>
                            <xsl:value-of 
select="transaction/LOOP_2000/LOOP_2100/CAS/CAS03" />
                        </_2100_CAS03_AdjustmentAmount>
```

I know I could use something like , but when I do that it fails or continues to insert one line only. I unfortunately can not share the XML file itself due to HIPAA, but I hope I have given enough information.

TLDR: I need help looping through each node in an XML file to insert all data into a separate lines in a SQL table.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] - including input and the expected output.

Comment: This is as much as I can include to due to HIPAA as stated above. The end output is only grabbing the first value from each of the nodes, instead of looping through each to insert a new line for the complete file data.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed not given enough details, so I will try to guess ;-)

According to what I find on 835 from:

- https://www.healthpartnersplans.com/media/100017241/254_Electronic-Remittance-Advice.pdf
- http://www.michigan.gov/documents/835MDCHTraining4-2-03_63540_7.pdf
- https://www.emedny.org/hipaa/5010/5010_sample_files/835%20Inst%20Sample(Inpatient%20DRG%20Retro).txt

I have created a sample XML instance that should resemble your one:

```
<X12_835>
  <LOOP_2000>
    <LX>
      <LX01>1</LX01>
    </LX>
    <LOOP_2100>
      <CLP>
        <CLP01>123</CLP01>
      </CLP>
      <CAS>
        <CAS01>CO</CAS01>
      </CAS>
    </LOOP_2100>
    <LOOP_2100>
      <CLP>
        <CLP01>234</CLP01>
      </CLP>
      <CAS>
        <CAS01>CO</CAS01>
      </CAS>
    </LOOP_2100>
  </LOOP_2000>
  <LOOP_2000>
    <LX>
      <LX01>2</LX01>
    </LX>
    <LOOP_2100>
      <CLP>
        <CLP01>345</CLP01>
      </CLP>
      <CAS>
        <CAS01>CO</CAS01>
      </CAS>
    </LOOP_2100>
    <LOOP_2100>
      <CLP>
        <CLP01>456</CLP01>
      </CLP>
      <CAS>
        <CAS01>CO</CAS01>
      </CAS>
    </LOOP_2100>
  </LOOP_2000>
</X12_835>
```

I hope I am not too far...

Then, if you run the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/X12_835">
    <lines>
      <xsl:for-each select="LOOP_2000">
        <xsl:for-each select="LOOP_2100">
          <line>
            <_2000_LX01_AssignedNumber>
              <xsl:value-of select="parent::LOOP_2000/LX/LX01"/>
            </_2000_LX01_AssignedNumber>
            <_2100_CAS01_ClaimAdjustmentGroupCode>
              <xsl:value-of select="CAS/CAS01"/>
            </_2100_CAS01_ClaimAdjustmentGroupCode>
            <!-- to be continued ;-) -->
          </line>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </lines>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You should get:

```
<lines>
  <line>
    <_2000_LX01_AssignedNumber>1</_2000_LX01_AssignedNumber>
    <_2100_CAS01_ClaimAdjustmentGroupCode>CO</_2100_CAS01_ClaimAdjustmentGroupCode>
  </line>
  <line>
    <_2000_LX01_AssignedNumber>1</_2000_LX01_AssignedNumber>
    <_2100_CAS01_ClaimAdjustmentGroupCode>CO</_2100_CAS01_ClaimAdjustmentGroupCode>
  </line>
  <line>
    <_2000_LX01_AssignedNumber>2</_2000_LX01_AssignedNumber>
    <_2100_CAS01_ClaimAdjustmentGroupCode>CO</_2100_CAS01_ClaimAdjustmentGroupCode>
  </line>
  <line>
    <_2000_LX01_AssignedNumber>2</_2000_LX01_AssignedNumber>
    <_2100_CAS01_ClaimAdjustmentGroupCode>CO</_2100_CAS01_ClaimAdjustmentGroupCode>
  </line>
</lines>
```

which might look like what you are looking for... Just let me know!

P.S. According to my knowledge, the usage of a "parent::" axis is not the most performant way to write such an XSLT, if your input file is big, you might want to use `<xsl:key>` ...

Comment: I am going to give this a shot in the next few hours. Thank you for taking the time to research and respond!